# Slicer not working properly after calculated item added to pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table, slicers

Before adding the *calculated item* `Kitchen+Storage`, the *Supervisor* slicer worked like charm filtering only relevant salespersons to a specific supervisor. But now with the calculated item added, slicer does not do its job and shows ALL salespersons (Wrong!).

First image is the source table, second is pivot table without calculated item and slicer, and the third is pivot table *with* calculated item and slicer.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Surely you mean Calculated *Item*, not Calculated *Field*? Suggest you amend your title and post content accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. It appears that Calculated Items are not compatible with Slicers. I can offer you two solutions, both of which require the data adding to the Data Model (Power Pivot). The first, and most straightforward, would be to create a measure for each of your Categories. This would only be feasible if your number of categories were fixed and not too large. Is this the case? If not, the solution will be slightly convoluted.

Comment: Looks like this is a limitation caused by the calculated items.